# Lottie React Native requiring unknown module "2236"

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie

I have problem with lottie-react-native.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.animationContainer}>
      <LottieView
        autoPlay
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          backgroundColor: '#eee',
        }}
        // Find more Lottie files at https://lottiefiles.com/featured
        source={require('./assets/gradientBall.json')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  animationContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
});
```

and it throws error :

```
Error: Requiring module "node_modules/lottie-react-native/lib/index.js", which threw an exception: Error: Requiring unknown module "2236". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run `yarn` or `npm install`.
```

I've tried restart metro and run yarn, but it still got errors.

Is there any way to resolve this error?

Comment: Hey, try to delete the node_modules folder, reinstall the dependencies and run the project again. Maybe it works

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue just remove your node_modules and reInstall the Lottie npm package using this command:

```
yarn add lottie-react-native lottie-ios@3.4.0
```

After that reset your metro cache using this command:

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Hope it will solve your issue.